# Is this the correct way of finding the expectation of a random variable involving a Brownian motion?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I wish to calculate the following expectation:

$\mathbb{E}[e^{-t}W(e^{2t})]$

Where $W(t)$ is a Brownian motion.

Can I rewrite this as follows?

$\mathbb{E}[e^{-t}W(e^{2t})]=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }e^{-x}\sqrt{e^{2x}}xf(x)dx$

where $f$ is the density of a standard normal random variable and where I have used that:

$W(e^{2t})\sim \sqrt{e^{2t}}N(0,1)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$e^{-t}$ is not random, so $\mathbb{E}[e^{-t}W(e^{2t})] = e^{-t} \mathbb{E}[W(e^{2t})] = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $W(t) \sim N(0,t)$, hence $W(e^{2t}) \sim \sqrt{e^{2t}}W(1) = e^t N(0,1)$.

Thus the answer is $Ee^{-t}W(e^{2t}) = EN(0,1) = 0$ because $\int_{\mathbb{R}} x f(x) dx = 0$ because of the fact that $f$ is odd.

The expression $\mathbb{E}[e^{-t}W(e^{2t})]=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }e^{-t}\sqrt{e^{2t}}xf(x)dx$ is also correct.

Comment: The expression $\mathbb{E}[e^{-t}W(e^{2t})] = \int e^{-x}\sqrt{e^{2x}}xf(x)dx$ is not correct.  The expression on the right has no $t$s in it, among other issues.

Comment: @user6247850, thank you, I didn't noticed